# what is the difference between getLayoutInflator and (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, layout-inflater

I'm confused between these two statements.
What is the difference and when can i use each one?

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_lists1, parent);
```

and

```
View v =  getLayoutInflater().inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_lists1, parent);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

second one is wrong

```
View v =  getLayoutInflater().inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_lists1, parent);
```

it might be

```
View v =  getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_lists1, parent);
```

> second one is called for the activity scope and the first one can be called from outside the Activity with the context

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you meant `View.inflate` as opposed to `Context.getLayoutInflater`? I think there's no difference, the former being a shortcut for the latter.